# Search by date and time in Exchange Web Services with AQS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm using Java EWS APIs and I'm facing a problem searching messages in my Exchange server using AQS strings.

I need to get all messagges received after a specific date and time.
Passing only the date everything is working fine, the problem is coming when I pass the time.
I'm not sure about the format I need to use in the query and the documentation lacks on this section.

Here's my code:

```
protected static void searchByCategoryAndDateOldVersion() throws Exception{
    ItemView view = new ItemView(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);

    String aqs = "category:categoryToSearch AND received:>=2017-03-21T10:35:00";

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, aqs, view);

    service.loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    System.out.println("Items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

    for (Item item : findResults) {
        System.out.println(item.getSubject());
    }

}
```

As I said, if I set the param received without the T10:35:00 part, everything works.

How can I tell the EWS to retrieve only the messages after that specific time?

P.S. I must use AQS as the Exchange version I'm using doesn't support category searching with SearchFilter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution.

Simply add a Calendar variable, format it with DateFormat and pass it to the query string:

```
protected static void searchByCategoryAndDateOldVersion() throws Exception{
    ItemView view = new ItemView(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending);

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017, 2, 21, 10, 35, 0);
    Date time = calendar.getTime();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    String dateLimit = dateFormat.format(time);

    String aqs = String.format("category:categoryToSearch AND received:>=%s", dateLimit);

    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, aqs, view);

    service.loadPropertiesForItems(findResults, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    System.out.println("Items found: " + findResults.getTotalCount());

    for (Item item : findResults) {
            System.out.println(item.getSubject());
    }
}
```